# Preserving referenceness when passing variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class Base
{
public:

    template <typename...Ts>
    void fun(Ts... vs)
    {
        cout << "Base::fun" << endl;
        cout << __FUNCSIG__ << endl;
    }
};

template <typename...Ts>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void dfun(Ts... vs)
    {
        cout << "Derived::dfun" << endl;
        cout << __FUNCSIG__ << endl;
        fun(vs...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int & a = i;
    Derived<int, int &> d;
    d.dfun(i, a);
}
```

On running the above code in VS2013, I get the types deduced for paramater pack values in Derived::dfun is (int, int&) where as in Base::fun is (int, int). Why is the referenceness lost when passing the arguments?

If dfun and fun were free functions, the referenceness is preserved. Why this difference?

If I change the signature of Base::fun to Base::fun(Ts&&... vs), the referenceness is preserved again.

Comment: The referenceness of an expression cannot be observed. That is, when you observe the type of the id-expression `a`, it's `int` not `int&`. (This is often abbreviated to "expressions don't have reference type")

Comment: @dyp but then why is it observable in Derived::dfun() and also if dfun() and fun() were non members?

Comment: `Base::fun` uses type deduction. It is a function template whose template parameters are deduced from the argument expressions in a call like `fun(vs...)` - here, you observe the type of the argument expressions `vs...`, which never yields references. OTOH, `Derived::dfun` is not a function template. It has a fixed amount and fixed types of parameters, determined by the class its a member of.

Comment: If you change your call to `fun<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);` you'll observe `int, int&`.

Comment: @dyp: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2015/02/expressions-can-have-reference-type.html ;)

Comment: @Pixelchemist Have you seen my comments there? ;) (Basically it's the reason I'm no longer using the abbreviated from.)

Comment: @dyp More than one, actually ;)

Comment: @dyp But isn't type deduction involved if dfun() and fun() are free function templates and not class members? Even then referenceness should be lost, but it isn't...why?

Comment: Type deduction is involved if you have a function template and don't explicitly specify the template arguments. Please show us the code using free functions.

Comment: Aah yes, I was specifying the types explicitly(unnecessarily) in the case that I was trying.. sorry abt that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During template deduction reference types will deduced to the type that they refer to. So `int&` will be deduced to an `int`. This is what is causing the behaviour you are seeing.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for a more detailed explication.

Comment: But isn't type deduction involved if dfun() and fun() are free function templates and not class members? Even then referenceness should be lost, but it isn't...why?

Comment: @Arun It isn't lost because the compiler doesn't have to figure out the types involved, they have already been provided in the signature of the function.